# Class Template Argument Deduction - clang and gcc differ

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, ctad

The following code [compiles with gcc but not with clang](https://godbolt.org/z/ttqGuL):

```
template<typename T>
class number {
    T num;
public:
    number(T num = 0): num(num) {}
    
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    friend auto add(T1 a, T2 b);
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto add(T1 a, T2 b) {
    // this compiles with both:
        // return number<T1>{a}.num + number<T2>{b}.num;
    // this compiles only with gcc:
    return number{a}.num + number{b}.num; // <== clang is unhappy here
}

int main() {
    auto result = add(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

Compilation errors provided by clang (version 10.0.0 with -std=c++20):

```
error: member reference base type 'number' is not a structure or union

    return number{a}.num + number{b}.num;

           ~~~~~~~~~^~~~

error: member reference base type 'number' is not a structure or union

    return number{a}.num + number{b}.num;

                           ~~~~~~~~~^~~~
```

**What is the correct behavior?**

Comment: Works with [msvc](https://godbolt.org/z/T6578F) so looks like some clang bug. Especially that version 3 works.

Comment: gcc is correct. This is [clang bug 44468](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44468).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Barry in the comments, this was a clang bug [44468](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44468) (and [47870](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=47870)).

Bug fixed. Code now compiles and works well [in Clang trunk](https://godbolt.org/z/51jdzd).