# A friend abbreviated template function - clang and gcc differ

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, auto, c++20

The following code [compiles with clang but not with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/HUJThm):

```
template<typename T>
class number {
    T num;
public:
    number(T num = 0): num(num) {}
    
    friend auto add(auto a, auto b);
};

auto add(auto a, auto b) {
    // the decltype(a) is needed to make clang happy
    // see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779242
    return number<decltype(a)>{a}.num + number<decltype(b)>{b}.num;
}

int main() {
    auto result = add(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

Compilation error provided by gcc (version 10.1 with -std=c++20):

```
In instantiation of 'auto add(auto:13, auto:14) [with auto:13 = double; auto:14 = double]':
error: 'double number<double>::num' is private within this context
   return number<decltype(a)>{a}.num + number<decltype(b)>{b}.num;
```

**Is it reasonable to assume this is a *gcc bug*?**

Comment: It compiles fine under GCC 9.x with -std=c++2a, so probably a bug.

Comment: @Taekahn in GCC 10.1 -std=c++20 it doesn't.

Comment: @KorelK: And that's why they said it's probably a bug.

Comment: @NicolBolas oh I mistakenly thought they talked about clang lol, my mistake.

Comment: Write a bug report, this will be much more productive: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gcc

Comment: @Oliv - done: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96106

Comment: Something must have changed to make this legal; I thought introducing a friend function within a class was distinct from any functions outside the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug in GCC 10.1.0, after working correctly till 9.3.

[Bug was opened and fixed in GCC 10.3](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=96106).